# Method to Sort 3d data

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a method in numpy that allows me to sort these 3d vectors in ascending order?

For example; I have the following input array and I'd like the following output:

```
input_arr = np.array( [
    [[255,0,3],
    [255,4,100],
    [255,2,3],
    [255,3,3],
    [0,1,3],
    ] ]
, dtype='uint8')

# Sort input_arr to produce the below

output_arr = np.array( [
    [[0,1,3],
    [255,0,3],
    [255,2,3],
    [255,3,3],
    [255,4,100],
    ] ]
, dtype='uint8')
```

I have tried the below but it does not produce the result I wanted above. Instead it produces the below.

```
output_arr2 = np.sort( input_arr, axis=0)

# Results in the below
[[[255   0   3]
 [255   4 100]
 [255   2   3]
 [255   3   3]
 [  0   1   3]]]
```

Comment: Your array is (1 5,3) shape.  Do you understand why the `axis=0` doesn't change anything?   You should be explicit about your sorting criteria; we shouldn't have to deduce it from your example.   If you don't like any of the 'duplicates' answer, it's probably because you weren't clear.

Comment: Since this closed, I'll just post a possbiel answer without explanation: `input_arr[:,np.argsort(np.sum(input_arr,axis=2)),:]`

Answer (score 0):

```
output_arr = np.asarray(list(map(lambda x: sorted(
    x, key=lambda rows: tuple(rows)), input_arr)), dtype='uint8')
```

This code takes a 2-dimensional input array input_arr, sorts the rows of each 2-dimensional sub-array in ascending order based on the values in the row, and stores the sorted arrays in a new 2-dimensional NumPy array output_arr.

Here's a step-by-step breakdown of what the code does:

1. lambda rows: tuple(rows) creates a lambda function that takes a row and converts it to a tuple. This is used as the key function for the sorted() function below.
2. lambda x: sorted(x, key=lambda rows: tuple(rows)) creates a lambda function that takes a sub-array x, and sorts its rows in ascending order based on the values in each row, using the lambda function created in step 1 as the key function for the sort.
3. map(lambda x: sorted(x, key=lambda rows: tuple(rows)), input_arr) applies the lambda function from step 2 to each sub-array in input_arr, resulting in an iterable of sorted sub-arrays.
4. list() converts the iterable from step 3 to a list.
5. np.asarray() converts the list from step 4 to a NumPy array, with the data type specified as uint8.

So in summary, this code takes a 2-dimensional input array, sorts each sub-array in ascending order based on the values in each row, and returns a new 2-dimensional NumPy array with the sorted sub-arrays.

Comment: Please provide some insight into your code, what does it do and why